# Copy multiple lines from object boxes to the clipboard as text/bullet points VBA

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard

All,

I have the below code which works successfully when selecting a box it copies the adjacent text to the clip board. (Please see pic);

```
Sub OptionButton4_Click()

Dim clipb As New DataObject
Dim clipc As New DataObject

clipb.SetText "" & "Customer XYZ."
clipb.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

[image]

Consequently Customer XYZ would be copied to the clip board. I would adapt / amend the code so which ever boxes are selected (Could be multiple are copied to the clipboard)

For instance if Customer XYZ & Customer YY was selected it would copy

- Customer XYZ
- Customer YY

To the clipboard. Etc.

Any advice on how I could adapt / amend the above code would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to decide if you need

- **Option Boxes** (only one box can be selected at once) or
- **Check Boxes** (multiple boxes can be selected at once)

to fulfill your requirements.

---

#### Option Boxes (only one can be selected at once)

Each of these 3 option buttons has a unique name to access its value:

```
Worksheets("my-sheet-name").Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.Value
```

*Note: The name of a button may be different from its caption/text.*

So this value is `1` if an option button is selected. And you can read the caption/text from that button with:

```
Worksheets("my-sheet-name").Shapes("Option Button 1").AlternativeText
```

---

So we end up with something like that:

```
Dim clipb As New DataObject
Dim clipbText As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("my-sheet-name")

If ws.Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.value = 1 Then
    clipbText = "• " & ws.Shapes("Option Button 1").AlternativeText

ElseIf ws.Shapes("Option Button 2").ControlFormat.value = 1 Then
    clipbText = "• " & ws.Shapes("Option Button 2").AlternativeText

ElseIf ws.Shapes("Option Button 3").ControlFormat.value = 1 Then
    clipbText = "• " & ws.Shapes("Option Button 3").AlternativeText

End If

clipb.SetText clipbText
clipb.PutInClipboard
```

*Note that you have to adjust your sheet name and option button names.*

---

#### Check Boxes (multiple can be selected at once)

If you need to select more than one box at the same time you need check boxes instead of option boxes.

Therefore the code would look a bit different:

```
Dim clipb As New DataObject
Dim clipbText As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("my-sheet-name")

If ws.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.value = 1 Then
    clipbText = clipbText & "• " & ws.Shapes("Check Box 1").AlternativeText & vbNewLine
End If

If ws.Shapes("Check Box 2").ControlFormat.value = 1 Then
    clipbText = clipbText & "• " & ws.Shapes("Check Box 2").AlternativeText & vbNewLine
End If

If ws.Shapes("Check Box 3").ControlFormat.value = 1 Then
    clipbText = clipbText & "• " & ws.Shapes("Check Box 3").AlternativeText & vbNewLine
End If

clipb.SetText clipbText
clipb.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Works perfectly :)